# Integrate directly on surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

When integrating on a surface we always have to parametrize the surface and then convert an integral like $$\int_D f(\mathbf r)\ dS$$ to a multiple (double in the case of surfaces) integral like $$\int_{v_0}^{v_1}\int_{u_0}^{u_1} g(u,v)\ dudv$$

That's how it was in multivariable calculus and in reading up on differential forms it seems that after some steps we always end up doing this conversion to double integrals as well.  Is there some way to integrate *directly on* surface elements without having to convert it to a double integral to integrate each parameter one at a time?  I don't know that it'd be useful to do so, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 0):

When you say integrate, do you mean to compute the value of the integral?

Sure, there are situations where general theory will tell you that the value of some integral will be zero (for example, if the surface is closed and the integrand $w$ is an exact form, then you can apply stokes theorem and go home early).

But generally speaking Fubini's theorem (which is what you are using here to convert an integral over a rectangular region into two single variable integrals) is a very powerful computational tool. This is especially so because for single variable integrals we have the fundamental theorem of calculus, and can sometimes figure out exact anti-deritatives.

My understanding is that most of the time people don't actually compute exact integrals, so I guess with more experience in computery stuff might want to comment on the actual algorithms that people use to estimate the values of integrals taken over surfaces.